# MySQL SQL to add records to table based on presence of other records for same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if there is a way to do this in a single SQL statement for MySQL without using code.

I have a table where each row consists of ids and attributes. Id is not a primary key and there may be multiple ids and multiple attributes as so:

```
ID     Attribute    Expiry Date
10001  Attribute 1  10/10/2017
10001  Attribute 2  10/10/2017
10001  Attribute 3  20/12/2017
10002  Attribute 1  04/02/2018
10002  Attribute 3  15/08/2018
```

In the example above, ID 10002 does not have attribute 2. I would like to INSERT an attribute 2 for every ID which has attribute 1 but not attribute 2, however I don't want to add attribute 2 where there is no attribute 1 for that ID. Additionally attribute 2 should take it's expiry date from the same in attribute 1.

This can be done with code by selecting all IDS with attribute 1 and selecting for each where ID = ID AND attribute = attribute2, inserting the new row if it returns 0 rows, however I think it can also be done in pure SQL, probably using a self join, possibly sub-selects.

Thanks for any help!

Matt

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `not exists`.

```
insert into tbl(id,attribute,expiry_date)
select id,'Attribute 2',expiry_date
from tbl t1
where attribute = 'Attribute 1'
and not exists (select 1 from tbl t2
                where t1.id=t2.id and t2.attribute='Attribute 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert select for the id  with attribute1 but not both attribute 1 and attribute 2

```
insert into my_table (id, attribute)
select id, 'Attribute 2' 
from my_table where id not in (
    select id 
    from my_table 
    where attribute in ('Attribute 1', 'Attribute 2')
    group by id 
    having count(*) = 2
    ) 
where Attribute = 'Attribute 1'
```